# Read id with jquery and apply action to corresponding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a certain button to show a certain div. Now I need to update my javascript for every new button & div. As this will be connected to a cms, for every post it needs to work automatically. How can I read the id/class from the button dynamically to apply an action to the corresponding div?

Way of thinking:

- button_xxx opens div with id xxx
- button_xxx_close closes it

Here's the html:

```
<a href="#" id="button_001">Button 001</a>
<a href="#" id="button_002">Button 002</a>
...
<a href="#" id="button_099">Button 099</a>

<div id="001">
    <p><a href="#" class="button_001_close">CLOSE</a></p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div id="002">
    <p><a href="#" class="button_002_close">CLOSE</a></p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div id="099">
    <p><a href="#" class="button_099_close">CLOSE</a></p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// SHOWS DIV    
    $('#button_001').on('click', function(){
        $('#001').removeClass('movedown');
        $('#001').addClass('moveup');
    });

    $('#button_002').on('click', function(){
        $('#002').removeClass('movedown');
        $('#002').addClass('moveup');
    });

    $('#button_099').on('click', function(){
        $('#099').removeClass('movedown');
        $('#099').addClass('moveup');
    });

// HIDES DIV
    $('.button_001_close').on('click', function(){
        $('#001').removeClass('moveup');
        $('#001').addClass('movedown');
    });

    $('.button_002_close').on('click', function(){
        $('#002').removeClass('moveup');
        $('#002').addClass('movedown');
    });

    $('.button_099_close').on('click', function(){
        $('#099').removeClass('moveup');
        $('#099').addClass('movedown');
    });

});
```

Comment: could u elaborate what u want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your code using `startswith` attribute selector in jquery

```
$("a[id^=button_]").click(function () {
    var id = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).removeClass("movedown").addClass("mouseup");
});
$('[class^=button_]').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).removeClass("mouseup").addClass("movedown");
});
```

First snippet will select all anchor elemets with id starts with `button_` and bind click event to them.

Second snippet will select all elemets with class starts with `button_` and bind click event to them.

**Note**

If your elements are created dynamically, use the below code

```
$(document).on("click", "a[id^=button_]", function () {
    var id = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).removeClass("movedown").addClass("mouseup");
});
$(document).on('click', '[class^=button_]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).removeClass("mouseup").addClass("movedown");
});
```

**Edit**

```
 $('[class^=button_]').on('click', function () {
      //  var id = this.id.split("_")[1]; <-- changedd this line
        var id = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];
        $("#" + id).removeClass("mouseup").addClass("movedown");
    });
```

I changed the line, Because that element doesnt have id. So you should pick the classname instead.

You can use `$(this).attr("class")` to get the current element's class name. Then split the classname to extract the div id

Comment: Hi, first snippet works; the div shows. But it doesn't close, I think because the close button is inside that div?

Comment: @user3782713 please see the answer now. I've updated it..(var id = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];)

Comment: Indeed, now it works! (btw: classes are movedown & moveup). Thank you!

Comment: As I want to understand how this works, can you explain what your last edit does exactly?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. It helps to learn to write better code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with toggleClass

```
$("a[id^=button_] , [class^=button_]").click(function () {
    var id = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).toggleClass("movedown mouseup");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // SHOWS DIV  
   var elem = '';  
   $('a[id*="button_"]').on('click', function(){
      elem = this.id.split('_')[1];
      $('#'+elem).toggleClass('movedown moveup');
   });
   // HIDES DIV
   $('.button_'+elem+'_close').on('click', function(){
      $('#'+elem).toggleClass('movedown moveup');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without the need for regular expressions with a small change to your html

```
<a href="#" class="button_open_div" data-divid="001">Button 001</a>
<div id="001">
    <p><a href="#" class="button_close_div" data-divid="001">CLOSE</a></p>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

and then add click handlers for both

```
$('.button_open_div').on('click', function(ev){
    $('#'+$(this).data('divid')).removeClass('movedown').addClass('moveup');
});

$('.button_close_div').on('click', function(){
    $('#'+$(this).data('divid')).removeClass('moveup').addClass('movedown');
});
```

or a toggle function

```
$('.button_open_div, .button_close_div').on('click', function(ev){
    $('#'+$(this).data('divid')).toggleClass('movedown moveup');
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/XXE2R/

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution, but after changing my html and js, nothing seems to happen.